# Separar as colunas de um array multidimensional

Tags: php

No formulário tenho INPUT array `name=INPUT_1[]..` que são dinâmicos, clonados adicionados outros valores. No exemplo abaixo cada `INPUT` tem 2 valores, más pode haver vários!

Obs: **PHP 5.3.8**

Ao submeter o form tenho o Array.

```
Array (
    [INPUT_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 74
            [1] => 69
        )

    [INPUT_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 1
        )

    [INPUT_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
        )

    [INPUT_4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 88
            [1] => 3
        )

    [INPUT_5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123.389,89
            [1] => 12,33
        )
)
```

No meu PHP, gostaria de tratar o array acima para:

```
Array (
    [INPUT_1] => 74,
    [INPUT_2] => 45,
    [INPUT_3] => 5,
    [INPUT_4] => 88,
    [INPUT_5] => 123.389,89
)

Array (
    [INPUT_1] => 69,
    [INPUT_2] => 1,
    [INPUT_3] => 2,
    [INPUT_4] => 3,
    [INPUT_5] => 12,33
)
```

### Tentativa

Pessoal estou tentando:

```
$array = array(
    'INPUT_1' => array(111, 112, 113),
    'INPUT_2' => array(222, 223, 224),
    'INPUT_3' => array(333, 334, 335),
    'INPUT_4' => array(444, 445, 446),
    'INPUT_5' => array(555, 556, 557)
);

$out = array();
foreach($array as $nome => $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $out[$nome] = $value;
    }
}
```

porém só ta pegando os últimos valores de cada array:

```
Array
(
    [INPUT_1] => 113
    [INPUT_2] => 224
    [INPUT_3] => 335
    [INPUT_4] => 446
    [INPUT_5] => 557
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
<?php
/*EXEMPLO DO ARRAY DE INPUT*/
$input = array('INPUT_1'=>array(74,69),'INPUT_2'=>array(45,1));
print_r($input);

$a = array();//Array que conterá os valores do índice 0
$b = array();//Array que conterá os valores do índice 1
//percorre o array INPUT
foreach($input as $key => $in){
    //colocar o primeiro valor no array $a com a chave do array principal
    $a[$key] = $in[0];
    //colocar o segundo valor no array $b com a chave do array principal
    $b[$key] = $in[1];
}
//imprime
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

**[Exemplo IDEONE](https://ideone.com/gbxz8S)**

**EDIT**

Se o array tiver quantidade dinâmicas de índices a solução é criar outro array de saída com os valores separados, exemplo:

```
<?php
$input = array('INPUT_1'=>array(74,69,189,155),'INPUT_2'=>array(45,1,10));
echo "****ENTRADA****".PHP_EOL;
print_r($input);

$out = array();

foreach($input as $key => $in){
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($in); $i++){
        $out[$key][$i] = $in[$i];
    }
}
echo "****SAÍDA****".PHP_EOL;
print_r($out);
```

**[EXEMPLO IDEONE 2](https://ideone.com/FABVCB)**

Comment: não serviu amigo :´(

Comment: @smigol O que não serviu, qual o erro? o array é diferente?

Comment: seu exemplo ta limitado 2 colunas, os valores dentro do array INPUT é dinamico, pode haver varios

Comment: @smigol veja a edição se atende.

Comment: agora ficou show! Obrigado meu velho.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma prática que encontrei foi utilizar desta forma, veja se lhe atende:

```
<?php

$array = array(
                array('74','69'),
                array('45','1'),
                array('5','2'),
                array('88','3'),
                array('123.389,89', '12,33'),           );

$arrayA = array(); $arrayB = array();


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {    
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 0) {               
            array_push($arrayB, $v);        
        } 
        else {          
            array_push($arrayA, $v);        
        }   
    } 
}

var_dump('<pre>',$arrayA,$arrayB);
```

https://ideone.com/scZwIu

Comment: seu exemplo ta limitado a 2 valores, podem haver vários, é dinâmico a inclusão

Comment: @smigol é verdade, mas ele é um ponto de partida para sua solução

Comment: @smigol outra coisa que é bem importante frisar, pelo que vi essa informação sobre ser "dinâmico" foi inserida após a resposta aonde não tinhamos como prever isto e não necessariamente você irá encontrar a resposta completa aqui e sim uma base para chegar nela

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira é utilizar as ferramentas que a linguagem te oferece. Lembre-se que linguagem de programação te permite evitar fazer trabalhos repetitivos. Se o fizer, algo não está de acordo. Por exemplo, o PHP fornece a função [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) que retorna um *array* com os valores presentes em uma determinada coluna. Então, considerando o exemplo:

```
$arr = [
  ['74','69'],
  ['45','1'],
  ['5','2'],
  ['88','3'],
  ['123.389,89', '12,33'],
];
```

Basta fazer:

```
array_column($arr, 0);
```

Para obter:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 74
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 88
    [4] => 123.389,89
)
```

E

```
array_column($arr, 1);
```

Para obter:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 69
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 12,33
)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OEis2Q).

Comment: Essa eu não tinha utilizado ainda muito boa solução

Comment: O sistema tem o php 5.3.8

Answer (score 0):

A partir do PHP 5.5.0 existe a função [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Exemplo de uso, similar ao seu caso:

```
$arr = array(
    array('74','69'),
    array('45','1'),
    array('5','2'),
    array('88','3')
);

//Pega todos do primeiro índice (0)
$a = array_column($arr, 0);
print_r($a);

//Pega todos do segundo índice (1)
$b = array_column($arr, 1);
print_r($b);
```

Lembre-se que nem sempre um código menor é sinônimo de melhor performance.

Esteja também ciente de que é disponível somente a partir da versão 5.5.0

Como ainda existem ambientes com versão inferior, é recomendável evitar funções novas se o seu projeto será usado em ambientes variados. Caso contrário, terá que criar uma condicional que verifique a versão do PHP ou se a função existe.

Comment: O sistema o php é o 5.3.8